# React equivalent of toggleClass/addClass/removeClass

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React and am trying to achieve something that I was able to do quite easily before with jQuery. I want to do this purely in React though and have found a solution that gets me part of the way there but not entirely...

Basically I have a div that houses text. By default I have a class that sets a height to that element, I then have another class that removes the height restriction allowing for all the content to be visible.

In jQuery it would have been a simple one or two lines to remove the restricted height class and add on my non-restricted one.

Here is my React code thus far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import arrow from "./img/down-arrow.png";


class UserGen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          active: false
        }
    }
      
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
          active: !this.state.active
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="user-generated col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-sm-12">   
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className= {this.state.active ? " user-generated-inner ug-expanded" : " user-generated-inner ug-collapsed"}>
                <h4>User Generated Summary</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempus auctor magna in fermentum. Sed et arcu vitae sem elementum consequat. Sed rhoncus vestibulum risus, eu tempor diam faucibus a. In efficitur accumsan scelerisque. Ut convallis nulla nec eros consectetur, ut consectetur tellus accumsan. Aenean quam tortor, consequat quis ligula quis, posuere laoreet risus. Nam id cursus ligula, et sagittis libero. Nam id dui vel diam eleifend accumsan. Donec aliquet, enim vitae dapibus maximus, turpis ante cursus enim, iaculis mollis nibh quam lacinia magna. Curabitur metus lorem, posuere blandit tortor eget, molestie viverra purus. Mauris in justo eget velit suscipit convallis. Aliquam placerat mi nec erat venenatis tincidunt vel vitae ligula. Nulla mattis justo id lacus posuere, in fringilla ex commodo. Ut at sem ligula.</p>
                <p>Duis eu diam ut urna egestas interdum. Integer sapien ligula, ultricies ac lobortis id, accumsan quis nisl. Donec pharetra condimentum mattis. Aliquam pretium lacinia ultricies. Maecenas vehicula nisi velit, dignissim consectetur nulla molestie ut. Suspendisse dictum porta semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras condimentum rhoncus volutpat. Fusce placerat, metus id finibus maximus, augue tellus hendrerit lacus, quis maximus magna erat et nisl. Aenean non leo metus. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas sit amet lobortis nunc, ut vehicula tortor. Duis maximus est vel tortor vulputate dignissim. Integer ac laoreet risus, et ultricies mi.</p>
                <p>Mauris est lorem, lobortis id accumsan faucibus, aliquet in ante. In porttitor nisl sit amet risus feugiat maximus. Mauris commodo dignissim fringilla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sodales, nunc et dictum placerat, mi lacus placerat enim, nec faucibus sapien enim vel felis. Fusce ultricies condimentum mauris, eget accumsan risus dictum id. Mauris tincidunt, ipsum at suscipit faucibus, tortor ligula volutpat ante, a cursus sapien lacus non sem. Maecenas consectetur, felis et scelerisque laoreet, turpis turpis gravida turpis, eget vestibulum magna tellus et ex. Mauris dignissim lorem non dui ornare ullamcorper. Mauris interdum bibendum augue. Proin egestas laoreet sapien nec sodales.</p>  
            </div> 
            <div className="expand"><p>Read More<span className="expand-arrow"><img src={arrow} alt="arrow for the read more" /></span></p></div>
    
        </div> 
        );

        
    } 

  }



export default UserGen
```

This works... but I've only been able to figure out how to get this running if it's the div housing the content that I'm clicking on.

Ideally I want to be able to fire the same onClick function from my "expand" class.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as is any constructive feedback on how this code looks.

Comment: why can't you move the `onclick` to the `expand` class element...?

Comment: There's no Expand class in the code you posted? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what isn't working. The code you posted looks fine, far as it goes. I'd use a enum instead of a boolean for the CSS class name, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally your code looks fine and you're almost there. You just need to add the same `handleClick` method, which I renamed to `toggleActive`, to the `div.expanded` as its `onClick` prop. This will also trigger the same action.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import arrow from "./img/down-arrow.png";

class UserGen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }

  toggleActive = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const containerClass = `user-generated-inner ug-${
      active ? "expanded" : "collapsed"
    }`;

    return (
      <div className="user-generated col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <div onClick={this.toggleActive} className={containerClass}>
          <h4>User Generated Summary</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
            tempus auctor magna in fermentum. Sed et arcu vitae sem elementum
            consequat. Sed rhoncus vestibulum risus, eu tempor diam faucibus a.
            In efficitur accumsan scelerisque. Ut convallis nulla nec eros
            consectetur, ut consectetur tellus accumsan. Aenean quam tortor,
            consequat quis ligula quis, posuere laoreet risus. Nam id cursus
            ligula, et sagittis libero. Nam id dui vel diam eleifend accumsan.
            Donec aliquet, enim vitae dapibus maximus, turpis ante cursus enim,
            iaculis mollis nibh quam lacinia magna. Curabitur metus lorem,
            posuere blandit tortor eget, molestie viverra purus. Mauris in justo
            eget velit suscipit convallis. Aliquam placerat mi nec erat
            venenatis tincidunt vel vitae ligula. Nulla mattis justo id lacus
            posuere, in fringilla ex commodo. Ut at sem ligula.
          </p>
          <p>
            Duis eu diam ut urna egestas interdum. Integer sapien ligula,
            ultricies ac lobortis id, accumsan quis nisl. Donec pharetra
            condimentum mattis. Aliquam pretium lacinia ultricies. Maecenas
            vehicula nisi velit, dignissim consectetur nulla molestie ut.
            Suspendisse dictum porta semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras condimentum rhoncus volutpat.
            Fusce placerat, metus id finibus maximus, augue tellus hendrerit
            lacus, quis maximus magna erat et nisl. Aenean non leo metus.
            Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas sit amet lobortis nunc, ut vehicula
            tortor. Duis maximus est vel tortor vulputate dignissim. Integer ac
            laoreet risus, et ultricies mi.
          </p>
          <p>
            Mauris est lorem, lobortis id accumsan faucibus, aliquet in ante. In
            porttitor nisl sit amet risus feugiat maximus. Mauris commodo
            dignissim fringilla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Fusce sodales, nunc et dictum placerat, mi lacus
            placerat enim, nec faucibus sapien enim vel felis. Fusce ultricies
            condimentum mauris, eget accumsan risus dictum id. Mauris tincidunt,
            ipsum at suscipit faucibus, tortor ligula volutpat ante, a cursus
            sapien lacus non sem. Maecenas consectetur, felis et scelerisque
            laoreet, turpis turpis gravida turpis, eget vestibulum magna tellus
            et ex. Mauris dignissim lorem non dui ornare ullamcorper. Mauris
            interdum bibendum augue. Proin egestas laoreet sapien nec sodales.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="expand" onClick={this.toggleActive}>
          <p>
            Read More
            <span className="expand-arrow">
              <img src={arrow} alt="arrow for the read more" />
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserGen;
```

If you wish to only expand and not collapse on the `div.expanded` you need to create a new function that only sets `active` in your state to `true`.

```js
expand = () => {
  this.setState({ active: true });
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT: Trying to answer the question in the comment section.**

(Needed to be here, as the text would have been too long.)

I'm not sure if I understood the question. However, I'm going to try to answer: Your component `UserGen` has an internal state which in this case consists only of the boolean `active`. Now in your render method you're doing specific things based on the current value of boolean `active` of the state. The render method doesn't care where the state change came from, it simply takes the state and does what you told it to do.

To demonstrate this on another level, you could even add your components `setState` method to the `window` object and change the state from your dev tools, without clicking on any element on the page. The component would still simply render whatever you told it to depending on the current state.

```js
// (...)
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    active: false,
  };

  // Do this only for demonstration purposes, do not ship this
  window.__userGenSetState = this.setState;
}
```

Now in your dev tools simply call `__userGenSetState({ active: true })` or `__userGenSetState({ active: false })` and you'll see that the render method doesn't care where the state change came from.

Comment: You're the best @RodrigoEhlers! So I implemented what you presented to me and it works, I now have the expansion of the div housing the lorem ipsum firing when I click on "expand".

If I could ask you one follow up question... now that I only have the onclick firing from expand, how does it know to expand the user-generated div with the lorem ipsum inside it. The onclick call is {this.toggleActive} which to my jQuery mind means the element that was clicked is going to have something happen to it. But that isn't the case here now

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 Thanks for the feedback! I've tried to answer your question in the original answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for the additional info in your original answer. Really helps me better understand how to "think" properly as I move forward with React. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want to do with using React Ref's.Here is a official documentation for how to implemet them.

https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html